# In RabbitMQ default exchange doesn't work 'COMMAND_INVALID - invalid exchange type '''

Tags: php, rabbitmq, rabbitmq-exchange

I'm learning RabbitMQ with tutorial https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-six-php.html.
I've copied code from example. But I get Exception when I run [this example](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-tutorials/blob/master/php/rpc_server.php).

`COMMAND_INVALID - invalid exchange type ''`
All previous examples worked correctly.
Why did it happen? What should I do to run it?

Answer (score 0):

I have RabbitMQ 3.7.16 running on my local workstation.

Here's a transcript of how I ran the code, which works fine. Some output is truncated:

```
lbakken@shostakovich ~/issues/php-amqplib                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
$ curl -LO https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-tutorials/master/php/rpc_server.php                                                                                                                                                                              

lbakken@shostakovich ~/issues/php-amqplib/so-57071954
$ cat composer.json 
{
  "require": {
    "php-amqplib/php-amqplib": "~2"
  }
}

lbakken@shostakovich ~/issues/php-amqplib/so-57071954
$ composer install
Loading composer repositories with package information

lbakken@shostakovich ~/issues/php-amqplib/so-57071954
$ ll
total 24
drwxr-xr-x  3 lbakken lbakken 4096 Jul 17 07:50 .
drwxr-xr-x 10 lbakken lbakken 4096 Jul 17 07:49 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 lbakken lbakken  180 Jul 17 07:49 composer.json
-rw-r--r--  1 lbakken lbakken 3118 Jul 17 07:50 composer.lock
-rw-r--r--  1 lbakken lbakken 1154 Jul 17 07:48 rpc_server.php
drwxr-xr-x  4 lbakken lbakken 4096 Jul 17 07:50 vendor

lbakken@shostakovich ~/issues/php-amqplib/so-57071954
$ php ./rpc_server.php 
 [x] Awaiting RPC requests
^C
```